# A batch that can write into a .exe cmd prompt?

Tags: sql, windows, batch-file

I would like to make a batch file that can write sql request into an .exe that is running as a cmd prompt window.

My idea was to put my sql script into an .txt file that the batch request and insert into my second prompt window.

I've found something about:

```
Type 'mytext.txt' | myexe.exe
```

But its not working.

What I want to do is a Batch that send my sql request into that .exe run as a cmd prompt, so I can automate that process.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends heavily on the capabilities of that exe-file.
What does it poll for ? Is it written to handle pipes ?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx gives you an overview of the command redirection operators.

Not knowing what the exe is capable of makes this question really hard to answer.